# How to parse pandas timestamp where the milliseconds field is not zero padded?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, strftime

I have a pandas data frame with a timestamp column formatted as a string. The time variable has micro second level precision but with no zero padding. Below are some sample values of the timestamp.

```
2015-05-12 05:25:23.904 UTC
2015-05-12 05:55:10.496544 UTC
2015-05-18 15:10:44.295 UTC
```

I want to parse this column and have datetime formatting. I tried the following options as stated in other stackoverflow threads but none worked.

```
input_data['event_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(input_data['event_timestamp'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%-f %z")

ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%-f %z'
```

```
input_data['event_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(input_data['event_timestamp'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z")

ValueError: time data '2015-05-12 05:25:23.904 UTC' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z' (match)
```

How do I parse this variable to timestamp format?

Comment: No format string should work fine no? `input_data['event_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(input_data['event_timestamp'])`

Comment: I just tried this and there is an issue.
`2015-05-12 05:25:23.904 UTC` is formatted as `2015-05-12 05:25:23.904000+00:00` which I think is wrong, since 904 means 904 micro seconds whereas 904000 means 904 milli seconds. It is adding trailing zeros instead of leading.

Comment: I don't believe so. You could test by printing out the microseconds with `input_data['event_timestamp'].dt.strftime('%f')` after the conversion to see if you get the expected values

Comment: Also trailing 0s after the decimal place do not affect value. `0.1` and `0.10000000` are the same number. This is similar to right padding on the non-fractional part of numbers `2` and `0000002` are also the same number. However left padding decimal places _would_ affect the value `0.1` and `0.0001` are _not_ the same number.

Comment: Yes I did and I got 904000

Comment: The approach you suggested takes a little longer than it would take if a timestamp format is already specified. Is it possible to specify a format in this case where the padding is on the right side?

Answer (score 0):

Convert milliseconds to microseconds by padding with '000':

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df.event_timestamp.str.replace(r'(\.\d{3}) (\w+)', r'\g<1>000 \2', regex=True))

0   2015-05-12 05:25:23.904000+00:00
1   2015-05-12 05:55:10.496544+00:00
2   2015-05-18 15:10:44.295000+00:00
Name: event_timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

From python doc:

> \g uses the corresponding group number; \g<2> is therefore equivalent to \2, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such as \g<2>0. \20 would be interpreted as a reference to group 20, not a reference to group 2 followed by the literal character '0'. The backreference \g<0> substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.

Comment: This is the _exact_ same output as `pd.to_datetime(df['event_timestamp'])` without doing any str replacements.

Comment: Given the comments OP is looking for something like `.replace(r'(?:\.)(\d{3}) (\w+)', r'.000\1 \2', regex=True)` based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68233114/how-to-parse-pandas-timestamp-where-the-milliseconds-field-is-not-zero-padded?noredirect=1#comment120593051_68233114).